# Argument became null when sent from client to server

Tags: c#, function, networking, unity-game-engine, arguments

I am trying to allow clients in my game to buy items and have those items spawned through out the network. To do this I am using two scripts, a script on the player and a script on the buy item button. I am aware that NetworkServer.Spawn() can only be called on the server, so I created a command function on my player script to spawn my item instead of doing it on the buy item script. When using this work around however, I get a **NullReferenceException Error** saying that the argument I passed is null. Why is the argument null?

Buy Item Script Code:

```
    void BuyItemAndSubtractGold(){ 
    GameObject item = SearchForItem ();
    int cost =  item.GetComponent<ItemManager_ItemStats> ().item.buyValue;
    if (item.GetComponent<ItemManager_ItemStats> () != null && storeMaster.gold >= cost) {
        GameObject newItem = (GameObject)Instantiate (item);
        playerMaster.CmdSpawnOnServer (newItem);
        newItem.transform.parent = playerInventory.transform;
        newItem.SetActive (false);
        Vector3 gunPosition = newItem.GetComponent<ItemManager_ItemPickup> ().gunPositions [0];
        newItem.transform.localPosition = gunPosition;
        newItem.transform.rotation =  Quaternion.Euler( itemThrow.originalRotation);
        storeMaster.gold -= cost;
        audioSource.clip = boughtItem;
        audioSource.Play ();
        storeMaster.CallEventUpdateUI ();
        sellInventory.LoadInventory ();
        playerMaster.CmdCallEventInventoryChanged ();
    } else {
        noGold.SetActive (true);
        StartCoroutine (wait5sec ());
    }
}
```

Player script code:

```
    [Command]
public void CmdSpawnOnServer(GameObject item){
    print (item != null);
    NetworkServer.Spawn (item);
}
```

Picture of error
[image]

Comment: You may notice the `NullReferenceException` occurs when the system goes looking for a `NetworkIdentity` component. It looks to me like you're trying to work around the client-server architecture, but that may not be a good approach. Recommend checking the tutorials over.

Comment: @rutter can you recommend me a good tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to send a gameobject through a command. The arguments that are able to be send via command, clientrpc, and syncvar are limited to certain types, and gameobject does not seem to be one of them. The alternative to doing this is using a supported type (like an int to specify the item id) or creating a user-defined value type (struct). The argument becoming null when being passed seems to be due to the fact that commands do not support gameobjects as an argument. Thus, you should send the value via a supported type in order to resolve the error. You could, for example, create a class which contains an array of the item gameobjects and then send the command using an integer specifying the desired gameobject's index; then use the sent integer value to retrieve the desired item gameobject.

More information on valid types is available here:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1001474/unet-parameter-restrictions-for-command-and-client.html

Comment: Wouldn't I still have to use syncvars to make sure that the gameobjects that I will be using the integer to retrieve exists in both the client and server?

Comment: When using the method in the link you provided me with, the networkID was successfully sent, but I get a null reference exception each time when I try to access the gameobject with ClientScene.FindLocalObject(itemID) or NetworkServer.FindLocalObject(itemID).

Comment: In response to your first comment - no, you would not. You could keep a script (on both client and server builds) which has an array containing the gameobject items. Since this would be on both the server and client builds (it could be just an empty gameobject with the list script attached), you would not need to check if an item exists on client and server -- the only time this would be needed, would be if weapons are dynamically created through gameplay (which they are likely not - and if this is the case, you can send more data or use a user-defined struct).

Comment: In response to your second comment: I think that the part of the link you are referring to refers to sending actually created gameobjects in the scene (not ones you are instantiating through a command). I just provided the link since it explains what can and can't be sent using SyncVars/Commands/ClientRPCs.